# Ruby String processing

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to learn ruby. What is an elegant way to convert `'"abcd" "efg"'` to a `['abcd', 'efg']` in Ruby?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'shellwords'
'"abcd" "efg"'.shellsplit
#=> ["abcd", "efg"]
```

Comment: Thanks! What can I use in Ruby 1.8.7?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by removing `"` character and then splitting by space

```
'"abcd" "efg"'.tr('"','').split
'"abcd" "efg"'.delete('"').split
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scan` which finds all occurrences of a pattern within a string.

```
'"aaa" "bbb"'.scan(/"([^"]*)"/)
=> [["aaa"], ["bbb"]]
```

Explained:

- `/` something`/` is a regular expression (which can match strings)
- `/"` something `"/` is a regular expression that matches strings starting and ending in `"`
- `[^"]` matches against any character that isn't a `"`
- `[^"]*` matches as many of these characters as it can.
- The `(` and `)` tell it want the bits I want in the results.

Comment: Note: This doesn't deal with escaped `"` characters.